# Any react-native plugin may bring android app from background to foreground

Tags: android, react-native

Currently we are developing an VoIP app using react native. We expected to bring app to foreground when it received a call when the app is in background. 
I know there's no way on iOS due to Apple's rules, but I guess we can do this on Android.

Is there any react native plugin for that? or any suggestion to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to bring the app itself to the foreground. You should instead use the VoIP functionality each platform provides, where the calls coming to your app will be handled by the corresponding default phone app.

For IOS [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) (more precisely the VoIP section)

For Android [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html)